# My API Route is not working; NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, server

I am working on an authentication API system using NodeJS. The `/Signup` API endpoint is working fine, but the `/authenticate` is not. Everytime I call the `/authenticate` endpoint, I get the `error message: 'Could not authenticate user'` even when a valid user is provided;
Below is my code. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var User = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function (router) {
    router.post('/signup', function (req,res) {
        var user = new User();
        user.local.username = req.body.username;
        user.local.email = req.body.email;
        user.local.password = req.body.password;

        if (req.body.username  == null || req.body.username == '' || req.body.email  == null || req.body.email == '' || req.body.password  == null || req.body.password == '') {
            res.json({success:false, message:'Ensure username, email and password were provided'});
        } else {
            user.save(function (err, data) {

                if (err) res.json({success:false, message:'Username or Email already exists!'});
                        //  console.log(err.errors)
                res.json({success:true, message:'New user created', data:data});
                console.log(data)
            }); 
        }
    })

    router.post('/authenticate', function (req,res) {
        User.findOne({username: req.body.username}).exec(function (err,user) {
            if(err) 
                return res.send(err);

            if (!user) {
                res.json({success:false, message: 'Could not authenticate user'});
            } else if(user){
                var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password)
                if (!validPassword) {
                    res.json({success:false, message: 'Could not authenticate password'});
                } else{
                    res.json({success:true, message: 'User authenticated'});
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
User Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');   
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;   
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model   
var userSchema = new Schema({

    local            : {
        username     : {type:String,unique:true,required:true, lowercase:true},
        email        : {type:String,unique:true,required:true, lowercase:true},
        password     : String
    },

    created_at       : {type:Date, default:Date.now},
    updated_at       : {type:Date, default:Date.now}

});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;      
    var now = new Date();     
    user.updated_at = now;    
    if(!user.created_at){         
       user.created_at = now      
    }         
    bcrypt.hash(user.local.password, null, null, function (err, hash) {
        if(err) return next(err)
        user.local.password = hash;
        next();     })  

});

// checking if password is valid   
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password); };

// create the model for users and expose it to our app   
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: I think your password handling is the problem - can you show the user model? Specifically the pre hooks and the comparePassword?

Comment: do you receive password in req.body.password?

Comment: and are you sure the mongo document structure you're trying to retreive is the same as you save?

Comment: I am able to save a new document (Create a new user), but i can;t read a specific user. Seems like my `User.find(...)` function is not kicking in.

Comment: I have a feeling that it will not wait for comparePassword to return why not have a callback and return return a callback with true or false and handle this.

Comment: on a side note get into the habbit of sending back proper http codes vs success: false only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just saw the bug its you have your username inside the local.

```
 router.post('/authenticate', function (req,res) {
    User.findOne({'local.username': req.body.username}).exec(function (err,user) {
        if(err) 
            return res.send(err);
        else{
            }
    });
```

Comment: Oh yes you did. Thanks for your killer vision.